# How to convert Json String to java Bean with generics using jackson

Tags: json, jackson

```
class A<T extends Animal>{
  @XmlElement
  T animal;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="animal")
class Animal{
}

//@XmlRootElement(name="Birds")
class Birds extends Animal{
 ArrayList<String> someNames;
relavant fields ..with getter/setter and annotation
}

//@XmlRootElement(name="Fish")
class Fish extends Animal{
relavant fields ..with getter/setter and annotation
}
```

I could convert Bean to Json String using org.codehaus.jackson . But when I try to convert Json String back to Java Bean using org.codehaus.jackson

```
JsonFactory jf = new JsonFactory(); 
JsonParser jp = null;

A<Bird> bird = null;
bird = inputMapper.readValue(jp, A.class);
```

I gets

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "someNames" .
```

I have put @XmlElement annotations on getter and setters.

Comment: Found the solution: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
http://programmerbruce.blogspot.in/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

See example 4 on the mentioned link. By putting 2 Annotations @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes, the problem is solved.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Birds.class, name = "birds"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Fish.class, name = "fish") })
@XmlRootElement(name="animal")
class Animal{
}
```

Note the `"type"` parameter in the annotation `@JsonTypeInfo`.

1) **While serializing**, `"type"` param is introduced by the Jackson framework.

In the case of Birds instance `"type"` is introduced  as                                `"animal":{"type":"birds", "":"" ....}`

Similarly in the case of Fish `"type"` is introduced as                                     `"animal":{"type":"fish", "":"" ....}`

2) **While Deserializing**, `"type"` parameter is used by the Jackson Framework  to instantiate polymorphic generic instance bean at run time.